# Help me find the difference between these two sentences

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference, active-vs-passive

> The World Wide Web was invented by Tim Berners Lee.
>   Tim Berners Lee invented the World Wide Web.

Comment: It's Tim Berners-Lee with a hyphen.